# What is the cumulative distance?

Tags: calculus

Assume I have 4 elements where there is a distance between each them. The distance between the elements is shown:

```
     e1   e2   e3   e4
e1   -    3    2    5
e2   3    -    1    6
e3   2    1    -    4
e4   5    6    4    -
```

For each of the elements, the distance from each elements to the other elements is the sum of its distance to the others. In this case, the result of the distance sum is:

```
e1   e2   e3   e4
10   10   7    15
```

Is the sum of the distance called the cumulative distance? Can I say the cumulative distance of `e1` is 10?

Comment: You can define a term to be whatever you want it to be, just ensure that it can easily make sense to someone else. In such cases, I generally prefer to go with "sum of distances (to other elements)" which is much clearer what I mean compared to "cumulative distance". Of course, you could also call it "pink elephant distance".

Comment: @CalvinLin But does it make sense to call it "cumulative distance"? I'm just afraid it's misusing of this term.

Comment: Because "cumulative distance" doesn't have a well-established mathematical meaning, you could co-opt it for your own use in your explanations/papers. As opposed to (say) "cumulative frequency distribution", which is an actual mathematical term.